# Powershell Citrix policy configuration

Tags: powershell, citrix

currently working on a script to configure policies for a citrix farm. 
i have a few policies that have 7-8 settings each, and can add them individually with:

```
set-ctxgrouppolicyconfiguration [policyName] [type] [setting] [value]
set-ctx....
set-ctx....
```

Is there a way to read these settings into an array and pass that to the cmdlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with Citrix, but you could always create a list of settings in a CSV:

```
"PolicyName","Type","Setting","Value"
"foo","User","some","23"
"foo","User","other","42"
"bar","User","...","..."
...
```

define a custom function like this:

```
function Set-MyPolicies {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [PSObject[]]$Policies
  )

  Process {
    $Policies | % {
      Set-CtxGroupPolicyConfiguration @_
    }
  }
}
```

and put everything together like this:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\policies.csv' | Set-MyPolicies
```

The function uses [splatting](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/10/18/use-splatting-to-simplify-your-powershell-scripts.aspx) for simplified parameter handling (the column titles of the CSV were named after the parameters to allow this).

Comment: Excellent, this actually works better in case some of the changes need to be modified by someone else.  thank you!